# Cannot run VOLTTRON weather agent

Tags: volttron

Recently, we have been working on publishing and subscribing weather information for building load prediction. When we try to run the weather agent, there are errors as shown below:

[image]

We stick to every instruction in the VOLLTRON 3.0 user guide and it still doesn't work. How to fix that problem? Thank you!

Comment: Liang please mark the answer below as correct if this helped you

Answer (score 0):

This usually means that there is a problem with the key or a problem connecting with weatherunderground.

You can manually verify your key and connection with:

Replace  with  your own key

`curl http://api.wunderground.com/api/<your key>/conditions/q/37918.json`